# " 'NSData' is not convertible to 'Data' " - while building project in swift on xcode Version 8.3 (8E162)

Tags: swift, xcode, build

I have been getting this strange error while build in a project, after resent updating of xcode. Any help will be appreciated.

Thankx and Regards
Sanjay.

```
if let dataFromFilePathString = NSData(contentsOfFile: DataJsonFilePath) {
            var dictionary:[String:Any]? = [:]
            let data = (data: dataFromFilePathString as Data) // ERROR
```

Comment: The last line makes no sense, it should be just `let data = dataFromFilePathString as Data`

Answer (score -1):

With the hint from @Martin R , I could correct the code as under.

```
        let url = NSURL(string: DataJsonFilePath)
        let dataFromFilePathString = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL) as Data?
        var dictionary:[String:Any]? = [:]
        if let data = dataFromFilePathString {
```

Thankx..